# keybd_event won't work with parenthesis and some other characters

Tags: c, windows, keyboard, ascii, quote

I'm working on a virtual keyboard for windows CE and i can't emit a input event using a parenthesis or a double quote (and probably other characters i havn't tested).

I'm using the parenthesis keycodes 0x28 and 0x29, but it simply doesn't work. When i want to send say a 'A', i just have to send shift, then 0x41 ('A'), then shift again, but parenthesis won't work, no matter if i use shift or not.

```
keybd_event(0x28, 0, 0, 0);
```

I'm not sending the key up event on WindowsCE.

Any help would be really appreciated !

Comment: 28 and 29 are [clearly wrong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx).  The virtual key code does not match the ASCII code.

Comment: I know, but parenthesis keycodes are not given in the MSDN documentation, or i am not able to find them. I found brackets, subscripts, etc, but not parenthesis. :(

Comment: @Hans Passant
It would really help if you knew them by the way :D

Comment: On my laptop I get a ( by pressing Shift+9.  So the virtual key code is 0x39.  I don't know what a CE device keyboard looks like in your neck of the woods, language matters.

Comment: Thanks i will try this. Keyboards actually look like nothing, they are manufacturer and even device model specific :)

Comment: @Hans Passant
0x39 indeed, i love you xD

Comment: @Hans Passant
By luck would you also know the code for the other parenthesis ? I tried adjacent codes (0x38 ans 0x40) but they are not the right ones. How do you do ')' on your laptop ? :) EDIT : It seems to be 0 + shift

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Hans Passant for the answer :

```
shift -> 0x39 -> shift for '('
shift -> 0x30 -> shift for ')'
```

With shift 0x10